# Using a path in Web Worker importScripts()

Tags: javascript, html, web-worker

I have a script in `app/hello.js` that instantiates a web worker that is in `app/vendor/flac`.  The worker itself also does some `importScripts()` of scripts in that same `app/vendor/flac` directory.

My problem is that importScripts() keeps trying to import those scripts from the root directory (same directory that `app/hello.js` is in) instead of `app/vendor/flac`.  How do I set it so that importScripts looks for the scripts in the same directory as the worker, without having to put in a path each time I want to importScripts()?

Comment: The spec (https://www.w3.org/TR/workers/) is pretty clear about workers loading relative to the script calling `importScripts()`.  Care to share some code?

Comment: I think this is a browser related issue. It looks like IE & FF are treating the paths relative but Chrome checks the path from the root directory.